# OSM - Geometry Requirements for Lines/Roads

Tags: openstreetmap

Are there a set of rules for how OSM handles line geometry? Specifically I am looking for the resolution/spacing of points that make up a polyline/linestring road - is this something that OSM controls?

Comment: Have you already read https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements?

Comment: yes, and I can see a way is defined by a polyline of up to 2,000 points. But I can't find the specific requirements for geometric design/frequency of points. How does OSM design curvature along ways?

Comment: There are no specific requirements. You can have a curve with only three points or with 50 points. What is your actual problem?